# iTextSharp cutting off pdf metadata at 255 characters

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to read metadata tags from a pdf file, however it cuts off at 255 characters even in mid tag. Is there a PDF character count for metadata at 255 or is something else going on. We were able to add tags past the count which leads me to think that it is not a count issue.

My code is as follows:

```
 var reader = new PdfReader(fileToCopy);
 var s = reader.Info["Keywords"];

 string[] partsArray = s.Split(';');

 foreach (var part in partsArray)
 {
    unrelated code here
 }
```

When I inspect 's' in Visual Studio it shows me all the tags found in said file however I can see the last tag in the string is cut off, which also leaves out the other tags that follow. It does stop right at the 255 character count.

Any help would be great!

Comment: iTextSharp is no longer supported for users, only for paying customers. Since the update from iTextSharp 5 to iText 7, we now talk about iText, *not* iTextSharp. That is also the reason why you can't tag any question using the iTextSharp tag anymore. We would appreciate it if you followed this policy and stopped talking about iTextSharp, it is now called iText for .NET. Also: please tell us if this problem also exists in iText 7. If so, someone will look at it; if not, you'll have to hope from help from a volunteer.

Comment: My apologies, it is listed as iTextSharp in Visual Studio NuGet packages still and that is why I stated it as such. I will look into this issue using iText 7 and report back

Comment: If I look at iTextSharp on NuGet then I clearly see confirmation of what Bruno wrote: https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/

Comment: @BenjaminPletcher: which itextsharp version did you originally use? Some (parts) of the comments are not helpful. If you don't use the the right tag then many potential users don't get informed. The tag should have been marked 'deprecated' or someting like that. And 2nd) I can understand Benjamin point of you when looking at the nuget page. Because it is full of iTextSharp references/mentions - it even uses the itextsharp tag itself :-D

Comment: @Lonzak I am/was using v5.5.12. I only used iTextSharp because there were more references to it than iText online when looking for something that parse metadata. Looking back at the packages, the one that I have installed only states that it is a port of iText which i wouldn't have known better that this version is now depreciated. I actually believe that my issue is more in line with the PDF file itself, but thank you all for the help.

Comment: Yes that would be my guess as well. Is it possible to provide your PDF file?